# MS Excel: Generate a value depending on conditions

Tags: excel

I am trying to make an Excel sheet. In which, I want to put 12 pairs of conditions. This means, I want to give two values, and depending on them, it will generate an output.

For example:

```
a1<  50 and b1<5 then it should print 100
a1>= 50 and a1<100 and b1<5 then it should print 200
a1>= 100 and a1<200 and b1<5 then it should print 300
a1>= 200 and a1<500 and b1<5 then it should print 400
```

I tried this:

```
=if(AND(A1<=75,B1<=5),1.341,AND(A1>=76,B1<=5,A1<=150),1.341,AND(A1>=151,A1<=350,B1<=5),1.408,AND(A1>350,B1<=5),1.475)
```

But it's saying I have entered too many arguments for this function.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` takes only 3 arguments: `(condition, value if condition is true, value if condition is false)`.

So you can use nested `IF`s:

```
=IF(AND(A1<50,B1<5),100,IF(AND(A1>=50,A1<100,B1<5),200,IF(.........)))
```

But it may be simpler do it this way:

```
=IF(B1<5,100*(A1<50)+200*AND(A1>=50,A1<100)+300*AND(A1>=100,A1<200)+400*AND(A1>=200,A1<500),"")
```

This second method works because `TRUE` evaluates as 1 and `FALSE` as 0.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? And what does `*` mean?

Comment: What kind of example? `*` stands for multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to nest the IFs:

```
=IF( condition1, value1, IF( condition2, value2, valueDefault ) ).
```

But this can get very complicated. In case of two variables(a and b) a more transparent solution is to create a lookup table: the first column contains 50, 100 and 200, and the first row contains 5, 100, 200, 500, while the rest of the table is filled up with the values, and then you can write someting like:

```
=INDEX( values, MATCH( actualA, firstColumn, 1 ), MATCH( actualB, firstRow, 1 ) )
```